# Types of filters used by Tesseract

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm working on testing how much can I improve results of Tesseract OCR recognition by different filters used on image preprocessing. But to do so accordingly, I need to know what type of filtration Tesseract uses by itself. By seeing results most probably only type of filtering is converting to grayscale and then applying binary threshold.

Does anyone know what types of filters are used or where can I find this kind of info?

Comment: tesseract is open source. read the source code... or just google tesseract filter ... https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality

Comment: Hey @Piglet, thanks for comment :) Yeah, I've focused so much on Tess-Two I forgot that I could check just tesseract itself. To bad that variable tessedit_write_images doesn't seem to work on android implementation :/ Will have to read source code to find what i'm looking for as you said I think :) 

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract v3 uses [Otsu thresholding](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/96f99520499cb8ca330e77d163cc2be20ac8d5a7/tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/ccstruct/otsuthr.h#L29) if I'm not mistaken.

You can use the [`getThresholdedImage()`](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/5a1e4e2ae878513a2e6ea2a753c2fb95f35ac68f/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java#L621) method to see the result of this.

And as you saw, the link posted by @Piglet above may be helpful: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality